# Buscar informação do package.json

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tentei fazer isso usando o require, mas não funcionou e deu esse erro :

```
ERROR in src/app/footer/footer.component.ts(8,21): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
```

Footer.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  packageJsonInfo = require('Workspace\develop\workspace-projetos_pessoais\geladeira-de-casa-ng\geladeira-ng\package.json');

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.packageJsonInfo.author);
    console.log(this.packageJsonInfo.version);
  }
}
```

Package.Json :

```
{
  "name": "geladeira-ng",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "npm prune"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.46",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Já tentei `npm i @types/node`

Comment: Não da pra simplesmente importar o arquivo? `import pkg from "package.json"` ->  `pkg.author`.

Comment: Eu realmente não sei, estou estudando Typescript e Angular e busquei a primeira solução no Stack Overflow gringo, esse import eu coloco onde no código?

Comment: Coloca em cima do `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';` apontando pro path correto do `package.json`.

Comment: Eu consegui capturar a versão fazendo o que mostrei na resposta, antes eu havia tentado fazer o import da forma como você falou e não tinha dado certo tbm, mas eu acredito que foi porque coloquei o path errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui recuperar o numero da versão fazendo o seguinte, mas não sei se é uma boa prática:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }
  public appVersion;

  ngOnInit() {
    const { version: appVersion } = require('package.json');
    console.log(appVersion);
  }
}
```